# Mapreduce: Function to extract multiple files from database

Tags: python, numpy, hadoop, mapreduce, readfile

I want to merge all the txt files available here https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/names.zip in one file. I am using below function but it isn't working.

```
read_files = glob.glob("/Users/myname/Downloads/names/*.txt")

with open("allnames.txt", "wb") as outfile:
for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: `cat *.txt >> allnames.txt`?